# Implementing Lazy Loading with Lightning Dual Listbox

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-duallistbox, lazy-loading

I need to implement lazy loading for a lightning dual listbox because I have more than 10k data to be put in the options and it is currently make the site hang/lag. I welcome anyone who have any other idea to implement this in a better way than I do.

What I have now is this, from developer console, I can see the scroll had been added as the event listener but when I scroll the lightning dual listbox, it is not triggered. Anyone know how to tackle this issue. Thanks a lot in advance!

Update: I decided to scrape of this idea and come up with a new solution. I'm using search bar and lightning dual listbox for the implementation. It works wonder!

HTML

```
<lightning-dual-listbox variant="label-hidden" source-label="Available" selected-label="Selected" data-id="customLabel" name="customLabel"  onchange={handleChangeCustomLabel} 
options={customLabelOptions} value={_selectedCustomLabel}> </lightning-dual-listbox>
```

JS

```
  @track customLabelOptions = [];
  @track pageNumber = 1;
  @track hasMoreData = true;
  PAGE_SIZE = 10;

  @wire(getCustomLabelList, { pageNumber: '$pageNumber', pageSize: '$PAGE_SIZE' })
  wiredCustomLabelList({ error, data }) {
      if (data) {
          const options = data.map(item => ({
              label: item.Value,
              value: item.Value + '-' + item.Name
          }));
          this.customLabelOptions = this.customLabelOptions.concat(options);
          this.hasMoreData = options.length === this.PAGE_SIZE;
      } else if (error) {
          console.error(error);
      }
  }
  
  handleChangeCustomLabel(event) {
      this._selectedCustomLabel = event.detail.value;
  }
  
  handleScroll(event) {
    console.log('handleScroll method called');
      const dualListbox = event.target;
      const scrollHeight = dualListbox.scrollHeight;
      const scrollTop = dualListbox.scrollTop;
      const clientHeight = dualListbox.clientHeight;
      if (scrollHeight - scrollTop <= clientHeight + 1 && this.hasMoreData) {
          this.pageNumber++;
      }
  }
  
  renderedCallback() {
      const dualListbox = this.template.querySelector('[data-id=customLabel]');
      if (dualListbox) {
          dualListbox.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll.bind(this));
          // Initialize with the first set of data
          this.pageNumber = 1;
      }
      console.log(dualListbox);
  }
  
  disconnectedCallback() {
      const dualListbox = this.template.querySelector('[data-id=customLabel]');
      if (dualListbox) {
          dualListbox.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll.bind(this));
      }
  }
```

Comment: Are your users going to be happy with that user experience? 10k items in a list that doesn't have search sounds terrible.  I'd look at using the list builder template, but you'll need to build it from scratch.

Comment: Ikr, but this is the designer idea and business somehow approve it. I just that one lowly developer trying to cater this. Thanks for the suggestion, I will try to look at it

Comment: I have implemented this duelling picklist here: https://github.com/rapsacnz/OrderedListGroup - because you have all the code, you can place a filter input above each column to limit the number of rows